# Non-orientable manifold with only orientable sub-manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Is there an example of a non-orientable manifold with only orientable proper sub-manifolds? Naively, one might think that the Möbius band is an example, but I don't think this works, because one could always just take a 'thinner' Möbius band, which would be a sub-manifold of the original but still non-orientable. But perhaps there is an example which does work?

Comment: $M$ is a submanifold to itself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant proper sub-manifolds.

Comment: Take $M-S$, where $S$ is a finite set. It is still non-orientable.

Comment: Okay fair enough, that was straightforward.. Thank you!

Comment: If the manifold is closed and you add the condition that the proper sub-manifold must also be closed, then the klein bottle  (or any 2-dimentional closed manifold) would be an example.